# tempory placeholders when doing string replaces... (Java, but general solutions would be useful)

Tags: java, string

This may have been asked somewhere else - unfortunately it's quite a difficult thing to google for.

Regularly when programming I find myself with constructs of the form (I'm looking particularly for a Java answer, but I'd be fascinated by a general solution)

```
String a = getStringFromPlace();
a=processStringInSomeWay(a);
sendStringToSomePlace(a);
```

My problem is that processStringInSomeWay(a) breaks if given some particular character, "£", say, and so I end up writing this...

```
String a = getStringFromPlace();
a=a.replace("£","replacevalue");
a=processStringInSomeWay(a);
a=a.replace("replacevalue","£");
sendStringToSomePlace(a);
```

but this, of course, breaks if 'replacevalue' happens to be in the input. I could just choose a ridiculous value of 'replacevalue' but that's *clearly* not good practice. What is the best practice in this situation?

EDIT - this is in the particualar case where one does not have control over the 'processStringInSomeWay()' method.  And I'm also interested in the situation were a has to be processed as one unit, it can't be split.

Comment: Make `processStringInSomeWay` ignore or handle better the `£` character?

Comment: It depends. What kind if transformation dies `processStringInSomeWay()` perform? Eg Can the length change?

Comment: Edited to make clear that I'm interested in solutions where one does not have control of the processStringInSomeWay method. :)

Comment: Btw, my first thought was what Alex said.

Comment: you could change the format, the String should be interprated at(Utf-8, Utf-16, ISO, or whatever)

Comment: @Bohemian.  In the particular instance I have (and in terms of finding if there is a guru-solution) the length can change, but a has to be parsed as one unit - it can't be tokkenised. :(

Comment: Then the only way I can see it working is to replace it with a character that is guaranteed not to appear in the input or output. As per answers, there are lots of characters to chose from. Personally I like the null char `'\0'`, but chose whatever works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite generic in the sense that without knowing what you need to do with these strings is almost impossible to give one precise answer.

Solutions I see are:

- remove directly the characters that the method shouldn't process (eg `replaceAll("£","")` )
- change the processing method to skip character with are not handled in current version
- split strings whenever an unwanted character is found and process them separately
- just place an escape sequence that is always the same for every symbol that is unmanaged (eg `replaceAll("£",escape+"£")` )

This problem is common in many situations and from what I saw you usually end up by just deciding that you have a sequence which can't be used naturally because it's used as an escape sequence. This is true in compression protocols, network protocols and in many other cases.

Comment: FYI your `replaceAll` calls may be changed to `replace` calls because you don't need a regex search

Comment: Thanks for your answer - To address 1) In general, I would expect that you need to be able to put them back ...  2) The question is looking for the particualar case where one does not have control over the 'processStringInSomeWay()' method 3) it's a sensible move in most situations, although I've edited the question in reasponse-today's problem requires the string to be processed as one... :(

Comment: if you don't have control over `processStringInSomeWay` then you must follow its contract. The function, if it's not able to manage certain character, must provide a way to escape them, otherwise you are asking how to prevent bad practice while using a fuction that has been badly designed. That's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Best practice is to fix `processStringInSomeWay(a);` so it doesn't break. i.e. so you don't need this work around.

Assuming you have to use a work around, there is almost 65536 possible chaarcters you could use, so you can pick one of those (or a combination)

Note: There are two non-characters `\uFFFE` and `\uFFFF` which are defined as "not a character". You can assume these will never appear in valid text. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: Ahh... the non-characters, I suspect, are what I'm looking for, but I'd like to leave it open for comments (I'm interested in the situation were one does not have control over processStringInSomeWay)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to replace, use a character that is not currently defined in Unicode.

However, I would change or overload processStringInSomeWay to take a String[], split at the character you are replacing, and concatenate afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about java, but could you do something like this:

```
a=processStringInSomeWay(a.replace("£",""));
```

It would remove the £ from the string passed to the process function without changing `a`

Comment: But that would remove all the real "£" when the string was passed elsewhere :(

Comment: it only removes it for the processstring function.  a stays the same.

Comment: yeah, you are not assigning `a.replace()` back to `a` so it stays the way it is.  you are passing the modified string to the other function.

Comment: ack.  missed that, and i even had it in my example.  sorry.  probably best is a not often used unicode value then.